# Postgres mistaking value as a colum

Tags: postgresql, string-constant

I have a section of a larger query, which we are working on converting from SQL to postgres that is giving an error of (Error: column "CEL" does not exist) and I am not sure why as CEL is a value nota column. I get the same result if I change "CEL" to CEL.

```
Select id, MIN(pos) as position from perphone

where personal_phone_type = "CEL"

GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Have you tried with single quotes? `'CEL'`

Comment: Yes but then I get the following error 

(ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CEL"
LINE 105:     where personal_phone_type = 'CEL')

Comment: I'm going to say there is some sort of hidden character around `'CEL'`, probably after. Add the complete error message to your question, there should be another line with a pointer that shows where the parser thinks the error is.

Comment: That looks to may have been it. I'm able to run it by itself successfully. I believe the Syntax error is coming from other parts of the query as this is only a section of a Left Join.

Answer (score 2):

`""` is for quoting [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) like columns and tables.

`''` is for quoting [constant values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

```
select
  id,
  min(pos) as position
from perphone
where personal_phone_type = 'CEL'
group by id
```